# C# How do I save runtime font settings

Tags: c#

I am allowing the users to be able to make their own font choices for a listview. What would you consider the best approach for this. Should I save it to the registry or to a file in the application folder, and what properties should be saved to make sure that the font is redisplayed properly when the application is restarted?

Thanks for your suggestions.

EDIT:

Thanks for all the answers.In answering one of your questions - The machine will not be used for multiple users.

what should I save inorder to recreate the settings.

if I save it to a delimited string can the font class parse this?
       "Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt, style=Bold"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Regarding where/how to save application settings see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-pratice-to-save-application-settings-in-windows-application#453230)

You can save your font as a string and load it later using following code:

```
Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic);
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Font));
// Saving Font object as a string
string fontString = converter.ConvertToString(font1);
// Load an instance of Font from a string
Font font = (Font)converter.ConvertFromString(fontString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx).

Really, you need to know if the application is ever shared across user profiles on the same machine. If not, you can get away with storing it in a config file. If it is, then you can use the registry (maintainable), or isolated storage (secure).

EDIT:
After your last update, you can save typed values in the app config. For example, If I want to save a color, I can save the value as a type System.Color, and the runtime will parse it for me. Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SystemConfiguration.aspx?display=Print) for more info and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the configuration file (most probably user settings section)... but it's best to avoid saving stuff to the application folder...unless you meant Application Data folder.