# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings is obsolete, warning

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, appsettings

```
var values = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "key", ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["API-Key"].ToString() },
    { "image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(photo.ToString())) }
};
```

What's the new way to use the app.config file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274852/the-name-configurationmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `ConfigurationManager` class in `System.Configuration`:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
```

So your code would change to:

```
var values = new NameValueCollection 
{ 
    { "key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API-Key"] }, 
    { "image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(photo.ToString())) } 
};
```

Make sure you add a reference to `System.Configuration` along with the `using` statement for `System.Configuration`.

Comment: If you can't see ConfigurationManager then please refer to this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274852/the-name-configurationmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Answer (score 7):

Use the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class

```
string ServerName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Servername"];
```

**Edit - added**

Note, you may have to add a reference to System.Configuration.dll.  Even if you can import the namespace without the reference, you will not be able to access this class unless you have the reference.

Comment: That's really strange, I System.Configuration namespace imported, but the ConfigurationManager class still shows up red. It's like it's not a part of the namespace. Any suggestions? I tried right-clicking and resolve, but no dice.

Comment: See my added note.  That threw me the first time as well. I think it took me a half an hour to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

With the ConfigurationManager class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The new class to use is the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class.