# Creating custom variable in web.config file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, config, html

I want to create a variable in web.config file and to use that variable in web forms.
How can I achieve this??

Comment: yes. I got to know about <customerror> tag but nothing about creating variable.

Comment: lol, I had the same question and *did* go to google first. The first hit was this page!

Comment: Actually, this page is now the top result for a search - Kudos to Chakri!

Comment: :p thanks, now I feel silly when I look at this question ;)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="message" value="Hello, World!" />
</appSettings>
```

in cs:

```
string str = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["message"].ToString();
```

Comment: Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274852/the-name-configurationmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context if you have issues with ConfigurationManager not working.

Comment: You forgot to mention to add the class in the code (`using System.Configuration`)

Answer (score 16):

You may try like this:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="id" value="12762"/>
   <add key ="url" value="http://localhost:10982/Redirect.aspx"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then you can use

```
using System.Configuration;
```

and use it like this:

```
string id=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Id"].ToString();
string url=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

FYI: The accepted answers for accessing web.config data are considered "Obsolete" now and should be replaced with:

Example:

in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="message" value="Hello, World!" />
</appSettings>
```

in c#:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["message"]
```

Reference: [ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings is obsolete, warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451140/configurationsettings-appsettings-is-obsolete-warning)