# Why call .ToString() on ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tostring, appsettings

I'm not sure if this is going to boil down to a matter of opinion, but I keep seeing a pattern in code that I don't understand.

All over C# apps, I keep seeing the expression:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"].ToString()
```

For a long time I thought it was just a quirk where I work, but I searched it, and it appears it's not just a few one-off things. People do it a fair amount, but it isn't really talked about as far as I can see.

This [blog](https://www.gibedigital.com/blog/configurationsettingsappsettings-obsolete/), for example, makes sure to call `.ToString()` on AppSettings, and so does [this blog](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/windows/c/how-to-use-app-config-in-visual-studio-c-net/)

Moreover, [all the programmers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451140/configurationsettings-appsettings-is-obsolete-warning) make sure to call `.ToString()` on the AppSettings collection.

To make sure I'm not going crazy, I rolled over the method in Visual Studio, which assures me that, yes, `AppSettings[key]` is strongly typed as a string and that "no actual conversion is performed" when calling `.ToString()`.

It would seem to me the only real difference between `AppSettings[key]` and `AppSettings[key].ToString()` is the possibility of throwing a NullReferenceException.

## So my question is:

Is there any technical reason for doing this, or is it a widely-recommended C# best practice for some reason, or is it just a weird quirk with no real meaning?

Comment: You'll see this pattern a lot in bad code. In general if I see `.ToString()` anywhere except perhaps a StringBuilder, I'm suspicious. It's a code smell. I've updated those answers you linked to so that they no longer call .ToString(). If you see it anywhere else, feel free to leave an answer calling them out on it!

Comment: given that `AppSettings["key"]` returns a string, the following `ToString()` it's at best not useful at all, and at worst can cause an exception if `AppSettings["key"]`  returns `null`

Comment: @mason Will do, thanks!

Comment: @EleanorHolley I originally said "leave an answer calling them out".  The should have said "a comment" instead of "an answer". You should only leave an answer if you directly address the question being asked. Just wanted to make sure I didn't steer you in the wrong direction. I swear, it all sounds right in my head!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest a strong reason why such code likely exists is it was probably originally written<sup>1</sup> before `ConfigurationManager` was introduced in .NET 2.

Previously, one would access the `Configuration` class with its `AppSettings` property that returned an [`AppSettingsSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection(v=vs.110).aspx). Which yes, unfortunately, has an indexer that returns `object` rather then `string`.

In upgrading their code to .NET 2, they'll have seen a suggestion to use `ConfigurationManager` instead and will have performed the minimal amount of editing to make their code use this class instead. And not thought about/considered removing the trailing `ToString()` that is now redundant.

---

<sup>1</sup>As discussed in the comments, it was probably originally written long ago and upgraded long ago. But this is the sort of code that will be copy & pasted *a lot* and so perpetuate itself almost virally.

Comment: Or, they saw some code on Stack Overflow or a random person's blog that uses `.ToString()` and copy-pasted without giving it a second thought.

Comment: @mason - yes, that's what allows such code to continue to be "written". It's gone viral.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any technical reason for doing this, or is it a widely-recommended C# best practice for some reason, or is it just a weird quirk with no real meaning?

The latter. There is no use in calling `ToString`. It can only do harm.

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is of type `NameValueCollection`, from which the accessor [returns a string already](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb(v=vs.110).aspx). Calling `ToString` can only cause a `NullReferenceException`. It has no positive effects.