# Database Connection Error "file in use"

Tags: sql-server, visual-c#-express-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 C# Express and SQL Server Management Studio with SQL Server 2012
I am getting an error when I try to connect a database to my Windows forms project.

```
"This file is in use.  Enter a new name or
close the file that is open in another program"
```

I poked around online to try to find a solution but none worked.   So i decided to create a brand new database and a brand new project.  But I still get the error!

here are the steps I use:

- First I connected to my locally hosted server
- then i right-clicked on `Databases` and selected `New Database` and named it `school`
- then i right clicked the `tables` folder on my new database and selected `new table`
- I added thes tables `student, course, enrolled`
- finally i threw some bogus entries into it

Now I jump over to VS

- I select `New Project` then `Windows Forms Application` and name it `Registrar`
- then i click `add new data source`
- select `database` in the `Choose a data source type` window
- then i select `Dataset` in the `Choose a Database Model` window
- then I click `New Connection`  I change the DataSource to `Microsoft SQL Server Database   File` browse to the DATA folder inside my 'SQLEXPRESS' folder and when i click the 'school.mdf' file i get the above error.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your database attached in the management studio? can you detach it and try.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your school.mdf is attached in your SQL Server 2012. You need to detach it.

Go to your SQL Server Management Studio, Right-Click on School, Tasks, Detach.

Unless it is detached, it will be in use by the the SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Thank you very much! I never would have figured that out.   Is there a way that I can still add data to it through the Server Management Studio or do I need to work with it through VS only now?

Comment: Hmm..  So i was able to successfully include it in my project.  But now I wanted to go back into Server Studio to edit and add new Stored Procedures.  However, when I reattach the database, it doesnt have any of the data loaded into it that I add through VS.

Comment: Hey Mike, I just checked through the steps you're performing to create a data source. Could I suggest you to choose "Microsoft SQL Server" instead of "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" while creating a "New Connection"? If you do that, I believe you can directly connect to your SQL Express database without the headache of detaching/reattaching.

Comment: I don't have that option.   On the "Change Data Source" window the option i have are "Microsoft Access Database File", "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5" and "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" .   If i chose the "Compact 3.5" there are no files listed in my server to choose.

Comment: Is it the same case when you Add a new data source?

Comment: Yes,  when i add a new data source, those are still the only options I am getting.

Answer (score 4):

You need To detach it.  If you don't want to do that, select "Microsoft SQL Server" instead of "Microsoft SQL Server Database File". Express versions VB don't have **Microsoft SQL Server** option.