# windows service project The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Configuration'

Tags: windows-services, configurationmanager

I'm coding a Windows Service.

I **added the dll and namespace** as shown below .

**using System.Configuration;**

//This line cause error but why ?

var settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

**Error:The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Configuration'**

Project Target is v4.0 and I successfully install and start service

Thanks.

Comment: do you see the ConfigurationManager dll in installed location? also look here seems dup question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274852/the-name-configurationmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: thank you I think there is AppSettings missing in my config. I added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appSettings is a readonly property so we need to define in App.config I think.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>

 </appSettings>
 ....
 <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllMan....
```