# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings is obsolete

Tags: c#, methods, obsolete

The following code works fine:

```
string api_url = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["api-url"].ToString();
```

with a warning message as follows:

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings' is obsolete: '"This method is obsolete, it has been replaced by System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings"'

As suggested by the warning message, I tried replacing `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`

```
string api_url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api-url"].ToString();
```

Now an error message appears, stating:

> The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

These are the namespaces imported:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not only do you need to add `System.Configuration` in front of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api-url"].ToString();` you also have to add the reference to the assembly `System.Configuration.dll`.

Here is link to similar question [The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274852/the-name-configurationmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to `System.Configuration`. The deprecated one was in `System.dll` but the same namespace `System.Configuration`

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to System.Configuration.