# can not find System.configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSetting

Tags: c#

I have a code which has the following line(.NET Win Form App)

```
label1.Text = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Text");
```

Above works fine but I get a warning that `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` is obsolete and must be replaced by `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Appsetting`.

The problem is VS  says `ConfigurationManager` is not a type or namespace in `System.Configuration`.

Im using Vs2019. I have using `System.Configuration;`

The interesting thing is when I click on potential fixes the only fix Vs suggests is to suppress this warning!

Comment: is this a netcore app? Net framework app? Which version?

Comment: Just  a .Net Framework  Windows form app

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274852/the-name-configurationmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: Yes it does .The solution is there.  basically I need to  manually add a reference to System.Configutartion. Seem to be a flaw in VS but is is the solution. Put this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer in the link did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

In my Case
having `using System.Configuration` was not enough. C# could see the obsolete method but not  the new one.

I had to add `System.Configuration` as a reference to make it work.