# loading form attributes from file parsing strings to ints c#

Tags: c#, string, forms, parsing, int

I would like to load my form size,background image,button position ect.. from a text file at launch.

What I would like to do is say something like this below.

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(appPath + @"\Config\Launcher.txt");
string size = streamReader.ReadLine();
this.Size = new Size(size);
streamReader.Close();
```

Now I understand I must parse the string to an int in some way then pass that to the size bit.

How would I go about doing this thanks.

Del

Comment: Have you searched for "parse string to int in C#" ? Apart from that, the `Size` structure has [two constructores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Size.Size.aspx), the first takes a `Point` and the other takes **two** integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size has Width and Height. Do you have a square, or how do you distinguish height from width?

to parse string into int and use it for a square, you can use:

```
string size = streamReader.ReadLine();
int iSize = 0;
if (int.TryParse(size, out iSize)) {
     this.Size = new Size(iSize, iSize);
} else {
 // error, maybe load default size
}
```

You can also use configuration files like App.config

Answer (score 1):

You should use [configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net). So Web.config or App.config
Also use the [configuration manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).

Your file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <window width="800" height="600" />
</configuration>
```

and your code should look something like this (untested):

```
this.Size = new Size(ConfigurationManager.window["width"], ConfigurationManager.window["height"]);
```