# Retrieving Value from Config file in C# Application Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, config

I'm having an issue, when I'm trying to work with a config file,
I've read a few posts here and somewhere else
but I can't solve problem in work,

In my question here,  I have added the Configuration.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="CA.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <CA.Properties.Settings>
 
          <appSettings>
            <add key="ab123" value="D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c" />
          </appSettings>

        </CA.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Declared in the document

```
string ab123 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ab123"];
```

But in the side , I show error is
" win32 Exception was unhandled -  System can not find the file specified"

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ab123"]);
```

When I run this code, `ab123` value is always null!
I'm sure the path is normal.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Focus on the problem. First get the config value, then try to start a process. You're not getting a value, which is a legitimate question to ask, but the process start failure is just a byproduct.

For your question itself, please follow some answers given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net

Comment: @Jonesy the question was about standard config keys, not a custom config section...

Comment: @OferZelig It's mean can't get the value?

Comment: In your xml file I don't understand what `<value />` does in the context of the configuration manager. What happens if it is removed?

Comment: @OferZelig: by "standard config keys", you mean `<setting>`?

Comment: I just realized it might be something trivial. You are specifying a `.c` file. Do you have a default file association set to open `.c` files? If not it would probably give you this error. Try this code with a txt file as an experiment and see if a default editor loads the txt file. To see if you can open `.c` files this way open a command prompt and simply issue this command `D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c` If putting that at the command prompt doesn't open a program then this would be reason Process.start can't either

Comment: It is trivial - he's probably passing in null.  See my answer.

Comment: If it had returned null the error would have been "Additional information: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided."

Comment: Perhaps, but clearly he's passing in null if he's using `AppSettings` to retrieve a setting from a config section defined for **Application Settings**.

Comment: @DaveSexton 
I use "AppSettings"
It can run
But can't open the file

Comment: @kyoko But are you sure that AppSettings is actually returning the full path?  Please confirm.

Comment: @DaveSexton I confirm it 
It full path

Comment: @kyoko So then @MichaelPetch is probably correct in that `Start` requires a file extension mapping on your computer.  I'm curious as to the results of his test that he recommended for you; namely, try changing the path to a .txt file and see if it runs notepad.

Comment: @DaveSexton I try to open .txt file , It's can't open it

Comment: @kyoko If it's the same exact error as before then there must be some other problem.  Please try to reproduce the problem in a [short but complete sample](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html), including all C# code and XML configuration.

Comment: @DaveSexton 
When I run the code, I find "ab123" value always null !!!!! I sure path is normal

Comment: Read the documentation that I linked you to and look at the example in my answer.  `appSettings` is in the wrong place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears from your xml config files that you are really trying to use User Settings rather than Application setting and that you have mixed some of the ideas up. I think a more correct version of a config might be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="CA.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
      <CA.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="ab123" serializeAs="String">
          <value>D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c</value>
        </setting>
        </CA.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

The only significant difference is the way you define settings. For example I changed it to:

```
<setting name="ab123" serializeAs="String">
    <value>D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c</value>
</setting>
```

You can create more settings just like this using a different `name`

The client code is a bit different as it has to find the userSettings, find the program property settings and then query for the key (like `ab123`). I have added some trivial error handling but you need to deal with the errors yourself. I simply return on error for code simplification. The code has inline comments to help figure out what is going on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            // Retrieve the userSettings gorup
            ConfigurationSectionGroup group = config.SectionGroups[@"userSettings"];
            if (group == null) return;

            // Get the program settings
            ClientSettingsSection clientSection = group.Sections["CA.Properties.Settings"] as ClientSettingsSection;
            if (clientSection == null) return;

            // This retrieves the value associated with the key
            string sFileName = clientSection.Settings.Get("ab123").Value.ValueXml.InnerText;

            // Check if ab123 has a value and the file exists
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFileName) && System.IO.File.Exists(sFileName))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sFileName))
                {
                    string line;
                    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
                    // the file is reached. 
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using Settings.settings to create and delete settings then the code can be simplified to this since Visual Studio will create bindings for your settings object that be accessed at design time and runtime. For information on using Settings.settings through the Visual Studio IDE please see this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx). If for some reason the code below doesn't work you can use the code above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sFileName = Properties.Settings.Default.ab123;

            // Check if ab123 has a value and the file exists
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFileName) && System.IO.File.Exists(sFileName))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sFileName))
                {
                    string line;
                    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
                    // the file is reached. 
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing two models.

1. [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6(v=vs.110).aspx) are defined by declaring a class that derives from [ApplicationSettingsBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase(v=vs.110).aspx), though typically you don't do this manually.  Instead, let VS create the class for you by going to your project's *Properties > Settings* tab.  This creates a special section in your config file that looks similar to the XML that you posted.
2. [App Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) are defined in a special `appSettings` configuration section.  Only these kinds of settings can be accessed via the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` property, as you're doing.  See the XML example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ab123" value="D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The reason that you're getting a Win32Exception is because, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx), it's thrown even if the specified path is null.  And `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` returns a null reference when the specified setting is not found in the config file.  (Just to be clear, it's not found in your case because you're not using the `appSettings` config section as shown above.)

Comment: I try it but  have problem "" win32 Exception was unhandled - System can not find the file specified""

Comment: <appSettings>
    <add key="ab123" value="D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c" />
  </appSettings>

Comment: Did you put it in the app.config file for your .exe project?  The config file that is generated for .dll projects has no relevance at all.

Comment: YES put in exe project

Comment: In that case, I'm sure that the path can be resolved now.  The error is probably due to a missing file mapping as suggested by @MichaelPetch.

Comment: IS  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ab123); ??

Comment: Earlier I asked about removing the line in your xml file that says `<value />`. Did you do that as well? I ask because that line actually throws an error on VS2013 when the program is run.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  By "Missing File Mapping" he means this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-file-open-program#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @MichaelPetch The entire config is wrong for AppSettings.  I'm 100% sure of that.  Dropping the "setting" XML into the `<configuration>` element (as you mentioned) is also invalid.  .NET throws an error because of an invalid config file.  I think he's past the config problem anyway.

Comment: On my VS2013 my App.config reads `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ab123" value="D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c" />
    <value />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
` . I then created that directory structure with his file in it. When program is run on my system Visual Studio launches and loads that `.c` file

Comment: Yep, because you're using `appSettings`, just like I described in my answer.  Note that it's not the same as `setting`, as you described to me in the comments of your answer and it's NOT what the OP posted.

Comment: Yes oops. I amended my Answer with the actual XML I used. I was unaware until you pointed it out that it was different from his. Now things seem to be making sense. My answer clearly shows exactly what was in my xml file. Thanks

Comment: Yea, I was confused there for a bit too.  I think at this point the OP needs to follow my advice and post a short but complete sample.  Based on the most recent comment left on another answer, it seems that he's attempting to use `Start` to "read" a file, so there are bigger problems here...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the specified file doesn't exist: `D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c`

Also, are you trying to store a key value pair? What about something like:

```
  <setting name="ab123" serializeAs="String">
    <value>D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c</value>
  </setting>
```

Comment: I check , the file is in this path

Comment: I fix xml 
But not this problem

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint after the line: `string ab123 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ab123"];` and see what the value of ab123 is (make sure it's a valid path).

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to `App.Config` file of application then I think you have additionally specified `add` element in the settings:

Setting should look like this:

```
 <setting name="ab123" serializeAs="String">            
       <value>D:\\ab123\\Source\\ab123.c</value>
 </setting>
```

Or use Key/Value attributes:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ab123" value="D:\\ab123\\Source\\ab123.c"/>   
</appSettings>
```

Code:

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
string sPath = appSettings["ab123"];

//furthermore check for path validity
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPath) && System.IO.File.Exists(sPath))    
{ 
   //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sPath);
    string[] readText = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(sPath); //to read the lines in string array     
}
```

Comment: I try your methods
It can run
But can't open the file

Comment: The path you are referring is not executable? If you want to open and read the contents then there are different way available.

Comment: This should be another question.

Comment: open file is ont use "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start" ?

Comment: Yes check I have read all the contents file in string array. You can use `StreamReader` as well. There are many different ways available.

Comment: Don't use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` it is used to start processes. For opening a file and reading its contents there are different ways. Search it or follow my answer.

Comment: Yes. Why don't you just try it.

Comment: "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement"

Comment: use curly brackets `{  }` under if condition

Comment: I have posted an example that uses ab123 from App.config and then reads the specified file line by line using StreamReader and outputs to console.

Comment: I use but can't open
I path is true

Comment: I find problem
"System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ab123"]);"
value is null
I can't get value.

Answer (score 0):

I am proposing another answer. I assume that this was an excerpt from your config file (and not the whole thing

```
<setting name="ab123" serializeAs="String">
    <add key="ab123" value="D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c"/>
</setting>
```

This is wrong, when I created my config file it looked like this but wasn not aware that was different from your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ab123a" value="D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm also going to assume that this returns a vale with your file name in it

```
string ab123 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ab123"];
```

You have stated that the file D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c exists. So I will assume that is true.

An issue I can see her if all of that is true is that you are not specifying an executable or batch/cmd file to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` . your code would be equivalent to

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("D:\\ab123\\Source\\ab123.c");
```

This is acceptable but Windows will see ab123.c is not an executable program. It then looks for `.c` file associations in the windows registry. The file association tells windows how to open such a file. If there is a file association it will launch the program specifying D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c as its argument (such a program would be Visual Stuido for example)

If there is a file association this call you have done should work if all the assumptions are correct above. If however there is nothing to associate `.c` with a program then Windows won't know how top open it and you will get an error similar to this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

One way to check if there is a default program for an extension is to simply open a cmd.exe terminal shell and issue this command:

```
D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c
```

If that launches a program and loads your file up then the association exists and my answer won't apply. I am suggesting this as an answer in the event someone does a search and lands here. This may be helpful for someone else, but may not be the OP's actual problem.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` does not retrieve values from the config section that you posted.  That section is for **Application Settings** only.  See my answer.

Comment: I added `<setting name="ab123" serializeAs="String">
    <add key="ab123" value="D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c"/>
</setting>` to my App.config and it did work.

Comment: Where in the config file?

Comment: between `<configuration>` and `</configuration>`

Comment: Huh?  There's no "setting" section under configuration.  See [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228147(v=vs.100).aspx).  Note there is an `appSettings` section.

Comment: So I can not use this method to open my file specified .c?

Comment: @Kyoko what happens when you load a command terminal and simply put your file name in. Does an application launch or does it prompt you asking how you want to open it? If there is a file association it will work. If there isn't, it won't

Comment: @MichaelPetch I must give it file path

Comment: Try setting abc123's value to a windows executable like c:\windows\System32\notepad.exe . That should launch notepad with a blank document if all goes well

Comment: Yes I meant open a command terminal (cmd.exe) and at the prompt put `D:\ab123\Source\ab123.c` in and hit <enter>. I did mean for the full path to be entered.

Comment: I have made an important change to this to reflect the fact that my App.config was not the same as the OP's