# Set a value in a Configuration File in a Windows Forms C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, configuration

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019.

How can I set a value (a path) in a Configuration File, so it can be updated and then restart the application with the updated value (without having to recompile the application)?

This is a legacy project that I don't really know. The most important requirement is to have the capability to change this path without having to recompile the application. This is what I've tried so far:

### Preliminary step:

To check what kind of project it is. Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/660938/6780663), I check that the `.csproj` file contains:

```xml
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

So, to my understanding the project is a **WinForms Application**.

Also, I've tried to seach for the GUID found in the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<ProjectGuid>{B1DD5159-A8E8-4DBE-964F-DB9679F60192}</ProjectGuid>
```

But the seach for that GUID gives no result, and also is not listed on this two GUID list:

- [List 1](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx)
- [List 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)

**Note:** The core of the question is based the asumption that this project is a WinForms Application. Please let me know if this the wrong way of finding the type of this project, or even better pointing out the right way of doing it.

---

### First step:

To edit the Configuration File, going to the Solution Explorer, in which I cannot find any `.config` file, 
but if I check the files of this project (via Windows Explorer), I found a `app.config` file.

I update this file outside of Visual Studio (I'll come back to this later), and add a `test` property. This modification is done following the structure found in the file, no external source to do this modification.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="LF10Demo.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <LF10Demo.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="AutoStepping" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            ...
            <setting name="test" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\Temp</value>
            </setting>
        </LF10Demo.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then, in the code try to get the value:

```
var appSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
string value1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
string value4 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("test");
```

None of which bring the value stored in the `app.config` file, in fact all of then brings `null`.

Then, update the `app.config` file following this post [configuration file in a Windows Forms C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114552)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="test" value="C:\Temp" />
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Which didn't work either.

### Second step

Going back to the modification of the `app.config`, discart this modifications and add a different Configuration File (after all, the `app.config` is not visible in the Solution Explorer).
This consist in adding a new configuration file `app1.config` following this post [related with configuration file in a Windows Forms C# Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114691) and also this one [Adding and reading from a Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864790).

So after adding the new configuration file, all my apptemps with `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` brings `null`.

Also, when adding the this new configuration file, if I choose `app.config` the show me a message saying

> A file with the name 'App.config' already exits...

So after all, the project is (in some way) finding that file.

#### Other related information:

In the file `Settings.Designer.cs` if I add the following:

```cs
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("C:\\Temp")]
public string test
{
    get {
        return ((string)(this["test"]));
    }
    set {
        this["test"] = value;
    }
}
```

And then using this line:

```
string value8 = Properties.Settings.Default.test;
```

Is possible to get the value, but this does not satisfy the requirement that the path can be changed without recompiling the application.

#### Other related links:

This are other links related with adding a configuration file to Visual Studios projects, I've also tried some of this solutions but without obtaining the expected results:

- [App.Config file in console application C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069254/app-config-file-in-console-application-c-sharp/)
- [Adding and reading from a Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864755/adding-and-reading-from-a-config-file)
- [Retrieving Value from Config file in C# Application Doesn't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656125/retrieving-value-from-config-file-in-c-sharp-application-doesnt-work?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your bin directory and you should see a file named YourProjectName.exe.config with a type of XML configuration. Whatever is in your app.config is copied here when you compile the project. You can change the values in code as follows:

```
static void UpdateAppSettings(string key, string value)
        {
            var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;
            settings[key].Value = value;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Edney, just one small comment for other readers, since I've not build the project yet the file is in `~/bin/Debug`, but I guess that after the build process the file will be in `bin`.