# MVC data annotations - dynamic string length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a data attribute for the string length defined as below for 40 characters.

```
[Display(Name = "Name"), StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The name cannot be more than 40 characters")]
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
```

Now the requirement is changed to get that value from the service.

Is there a way to get that value into these data attributes something like: 
string s = 50; //Let's say calls the service to get this value

```
[Display(Name = "Name"), StringLength(s, ErrorMessage = "The name cannot be more than {0} characters")]
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass a non-constant value to an attribute, so your solution can not be implemented.

However, you can pass a `const` value from config file. If you are accepting behaviour like the following: validation of the string will be of single maximum length for a whole lifetime of application and to change it you should reboot an app, take a look at [variables in application config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net).

If you does not accept this behaviour, the one of possible solutions is to store your `MaxLength` somewhere in database and create your own `StringLengthAttribute`, which will query DB (or another data source) during valigation in the following way:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class MyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public MyValidationAttribute()
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            int maxLength = //query your data source

            return ((string)value).Length <= maxLength;
        }

        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

Another possible solution is to perform client-side validation instead of server-side. If you will query your data source from the client-side it will look better, than querying it from attribute, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass dynamic value to the attribute, but you can retrieve the dynamic value it self inside the attribute implementation and pass only a key to the attribute. ex:

```
public class DynamicLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string _lengthKey;

    public DynamicLengthAttribute (string lengthKey)
    {
     _lengthKey = lengthKey;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
           //retrive teh max length from the database according to the lengthKey variable, if you will store it in web.config you can do:

           int maxLength = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[_lengthKey];
            return ((string)value).Length <= maxLength;
        }

        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

and in your model

```
[DynamicLength(maxLengths="EmpNameMaxLength", ErrorMessage = "The name cannot be more than {0} characters")]
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
```