# Reading keys from app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Reading keys from `app.config` is not working

I have 4 layers in my solution:

- Business Layer
- Data Access Layer
- Presentation Layer
- Shared Layer

I added this `app.config` file in the shared layer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TEST" value="ItsWorking" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and I included the `System.Configuration` dll in references

I tried

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TEST"];
```

but it returns null

Comment: You can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12892083/2889347

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` will read the `.config` file of the *current* executing assembly. If the code is running inside a web application (e.g. ASP.NET MVC or Web API) than your `appSettings` tag should be added to the root `Web.config`.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Move your comment to answers so i can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration only reads from the executing project assembly so you only need in the executable project and you can access from all your others projects.

Maybe you can use a configurationProvider with an Interface and with IOC you can access from all your projects.

Like

```
public interface IConfigurations
{
  string TEST {get;}
}
```

You use this interfaces in all your projects and only where you implement the properly configurations you implement the interface for a app.config, xml, .text, DB, or any source.

```
  public class Configurations : IConfigurations
    {
      public string TEST => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TEST"]; 
    }
```