# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings count 0

Tags: c#-4.0, configurationmanager

C# -  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings count is 0. And ideas? Here is the code:

```
  var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

                    if (appSettings.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("AppSettings is empty.");
                    }
```

Running in debug. VS copies the app.config to the debug directory and names it 
CBCuedERI.exe.config.  Here is part of the config file

```
<applicationSettings>
    <CBCuedERI.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="test" serializeAs="String">
            <value>one</value>
        </setting>
    </CBCuedERI.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

I also tried this and it returns NULL

```
  string sss = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get ( "test") ;
```

Answer (score -1):

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is used for the key value pairs in appSettings section

[Reading settings from app.config or web.config in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net)

Comment: I tried this after reading the link  and returned NULL.   string sss = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get ( "test")  ;

Answer (score -1):

Your config file is incorrect, you are using the key `applicationSettings` instead of the correct `appSettings`.