# What is the best way to update an App.Config file for C# in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration

I have been working on a file conversion project in C# using Visual Studio 2019. I have been asked to revise my code so that any file paths are replaced with variables that are called via the App.Config file. I am new to this method, as I was never taught how to do this before. I am looking for some guidance or examples if anyone could assist. I have tried any related articles or videos, but am still struggling. My code is below. I have updated any serve/db names to generic ones. Thanks in advance.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string fromPath = string.Empty;
        string toPath = string.Empty;

        // set path where the source xls file is
        string sourcePath = @"\\server\Data\subfolder\subfolder2\";

        // determine target filename from today's date
        string sourceFile = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yy") + ".xls";

        // determine if the target file exists
        fromPath = sourcePath + sourceFile;              // gives us the full path and filename to open

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fromPath))
        {
            // file exists, so process it

            // make our output file
            toPath = sourcePath + "import.csv";

            // do the conversion to csv
            CsvHelper csv = new CsvHelper();
            csv.XlsToCsv(fromPath, toPath);

            // renames one column to say 'idn_prod1'
            var file1 = @"\\server\Data\subfolder\subfolder2\import.csv";
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1);

            var columnHeaders = lines[0];
            var textToReplace = "idn_prod";
            var newText = "idn_prod1";

            var indexToReplace = columnHeaders
                .LastIndexOf("idn_prod");//LastIndex ensures that you pick the second idn_prod
            columnHeaders = columnHeaders
                .Remove(indexToReplace, textToReplace.Length)
                .Insert(indexToReplace, newText);//removes the second idn_prod and replaces it with the updated value.

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file1))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(columnHeaders);

                foreach (var str in lines.Skip(1))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(str);
                }

                sw.Flush();
            }



            // archive xls file to prevent buildup in this directory
            if (Directory.Exists(@"\\server\Data\subfolder\subfolder2\"))
            {
                foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\myName\Documents\Projects\").GetFiles())
                {
                    file.MoveTo($@"{ @"\\server\Data\subfolder\subfolder2\Archive"}\{file.Name}");
                }
            }



        }



    }
    //Move data in CSV file to a DataTable
    private static System.Data.DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path = @"\\server\Data\subfolder\subfolder2\import.csv")
    {
        System.Data.DataTable csvData = new System.Data.DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                }
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    //Making empty value as null
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return csvData;
    }

    //import DataTable into Server and database table
    static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(System.Data.DataTable csvFileData)
    {
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
            {
                s.DestinationTableName = "Table";
                foreach (var column in csvFileData.Columns)
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my App.Config currently. Sorry for the issues prior.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" 
    sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
        </startup>
      <appSettings>
        <!-- Name of the application-->
        <add key="ApplicationName" value="xlsTocsv"/>

        <!-- Archive directory for XLS files-->
        <add key="MoveTo" 
    value="@\\server\Data\subfolder\subfolder2\Archive"/>

        <!-- Server Name for import-->
        <add key="Data Source" value="Server"/>
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to put your values in the `app.config` file like so

```
<configuration> //this is probably already in your app.config file
  <appSettings>
    <add key="variable1Name" value="/mypathgoeshere/example" />
    ....
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

To access these variables you need these

> Namespace: System.Configuration
>
> Assemblies: System.Configuration.dll,
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll

and then in your file you want to access it like this.

```
using System.Configuration;     

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["variable1Name"];
            //returns the value of "/mypathgoeshere/example"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helps.

Comment: You're welcome glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio:

1. right-click your project,
2. choose Add->New Item.
3. In the search box, type "config".
4. Choose "Application Configuration Item".  This will add a boiler-plate XML file to your project named "App.config"
5. Add an `<appSettings></appSettings>` element as a direct child of the main `<configuration>` node
6. Within the appSetting element, create child elements that look like:

```xml
<add key="someKey" value ="Some value as a string, it could be a number, or whatever"/>
```

7. Add a reference to System.Configuration to your project if there isn't one.
8. In each file where you are going to access your app settings, add `using System.Configuration;` to the top of the file.
9. To get the setting, use code like:

```cs
var someKeySetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"];
```

At this point, `someKeySetting` will be a string that contains the setting you gave it in the config file.  If the setting doesn't exist in the config file, then `someKeySetting` will be `null`.  If you want to use numbers, dates, or enums, you will have to parse the string that results (preferably using the appropriate `TryParse` call.