# How to read the custom configuration settings in c#?

Tags: c#

Can any one look into the below piece of code and suggest me the answer.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**************" >
        <section name="ConfigurableCSV.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*********************" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<userSettings>
        <setting name="DefaultWRLFolder" serializeAs="String">
            <value>S:\Test Projects\files</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="DefaultTABFolder" serializeAs="String">
            <value>S:\Test Projects\files\sql</value>
        </setting>
```

How to retrieve the data from the setting tab at run time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading settings from app.config or web.config in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net)

Comment: Read also the major not accepted answers in that duplicate.