# How to read data from a .conf file in C#?

Tags: c#, config

I have a file, `application.conf`, that contains this code:

```
...
features{
    dev{
        features = ["feature1","feature2", "feature4"]
    }
}
...
```

How can I access that list of features from a C# file? I need to somehow import the .conf file into the C# file but can't find any way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net

Comment: @Anve No, that looks like its for XML. As you can see in my code sample, it is not XML format.

Comment: what kind is your project web application or console?

Comment: @Anve web application

Comment: I suppose that you do project in ASP.NET Core, then you can get config values by using IConfiguration interface, here you have example with json app.config file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1