# C# check if handler is present in Web.Config

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, handler, configurationmanager

In my Web.Config file I have the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="HANDLERNAME" verb="*" path="PATH.axd" type="HANDLERTYPE">
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Before I run a particular bit of code, I want to check to see if the handler is present in my Web.Config file.

Is this something I'm able to do?

I've tried: `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.webServer/handlers")` with no success, as this returns null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A `Web.Config` file is just xml, you can load and parse/read this to get what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading settings from app.config or web.config in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to check for the `Handlers` in the web.config

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path); *//path is the location of the web.config file*

    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNode nodes = root.SelectSingleNode("/system.webServer");
    XmlNodeList childnotes = nodes.ChildNodes;
    bool isExist = false;;
    foreach (XmlNode node in childnotes)
    {
        if (node.Name.Contains("handlers"))
        {
            isExist = node.OuterXml.Contains("HANDLERNAME");
        }
    }
```

you can check the value of **isExist**

The other way is to get the entire `web.config` as a string and check if it contains `HANDLERNAME`