# How can I not hard code a development/test/production-dependent string in a C# project?

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration

In a Windows Forms C# project, I have a URL to an [SSRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services) report and the URL depends on development/test/production environment:

- `\\dev\path\to\report`
- `\\test\path\to\report`
- `\\prod\path\to\report`

I was wondering if the URL can be not hard coded in the source code?

More generally, if there is a string that depends on development/test/production, how can I not hard code it in source code?

Comment: Read such values from App.Config

Comment: @NickFarsi thanks. could you provide some links for me to learn?

Comment: I think this post is a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892083/9969906

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be helpful in your situation, but you can also define configurations in your Build Properties and set conditional compilation symbols based on the specific runtime context.

[image: conditional compilation symbols]

So if you have dev, test and prod defined with different symbols...

[image: configs]

You can leverage that to do something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class SandboxManager
{
    public static SemaphoreSlim UIClosedAwaiter = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public static SemaphoreSlim SS_Boot = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static async Task BootUnitTest(TestContext context)
    {
        ResourceInfo.UTRoot = @"D:\Github\xamarin-21\sasquatch-net-standard-21\sasquatch-net-standard";            
        var dir = Path.Combine(ResourceInfo.UTRoot, "Test", "Logs", $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd}");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        TestBase.LogFile = Path.Combine(dir, "log.txt");
        if(File.Exists(TestBase.LogFile)) File.Delete(TestBase.LogFile);
#if SBX_SQFA
        UIClosedAwaiter.Wait(0);
        SQInstance.RunContext = RunContext.UnitTestFullUI;
        MainActivitySandbox.Boot();
        await SS_Boot.WaitAsync();
        await onBootSQFA();
#elif SBX_UI_LITE
        UIClosedAwaiter.Wait(0);
        SQInstance.RunContext = RunContext.UnitTestLiteUI;
        AppWOUISandbox.Boot();
        UIControlSandbox.Boot();
        await SS_Boot.WaitAsync();
#elif SBX_MOCK_AI
        SQInstance.RunContext = RunContext.UnitTestLiteInstance;
        AppWOUISandbox.Boot();
#else
        SQInstance.RunContext = RunContext.UnitTestPrimitive;
#endif
        SS_Boot.EnsureRelease();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
```