# Read Settings From .NET Core V6 File C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, app-config

I used Settings.settings interface in VS2022 to add some user settings and a connection string. But I am unable to read the App Settings.

Reading the connection string works using

```
string sDBConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MissingSamplesGUI.Properties.Settings.DBConn"].ConnectionString;
```

However, I cannot read the User Settings from the same App.Config file. Using

```
int iFormTop = (int)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager["FormTop"];
```

Does not work. How do I read and write these settings?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. It may help you look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-save-and-edit-connection-strings?view=vs-2022

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's done as follows.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.FormTop;
```