# Why do some C# applications have an app.config file and others do not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Why do some C# applications have an app.config file and others do not? Both of these solutions were initialized as Visual C# Windows Form Applications.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be deleted (for example, if it's not being used).  Also, auto-generation can be turned off in project settings... so we'd just be guessing at possible reasons without more details about your projects.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is created with the `Windows Forms App` template (i.e. NET Core runtime like .NET 6+):

> Creates a [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/) app that targets .NET 6 (or later).

and the second one with the `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)` template:

> Creates a Windows Forms app that targets the .NET Framework. For a walkthrough of this project template, see [Create a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio).

So while both templates will create a WinForms app they will have differences due to two different runtimes/frameworks being used.

See also:

- [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection)
- [What's the difference between .NET Core, .NET Framework, and Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38063837/2501279)
- [.NET templates doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/visual-studio-templates#net-templates).

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [this answer by @Guru-Stron](https://UpdateMasterSource) the difference between those two examples is the template that you have used to start the project and the associated .Net framework.

Since .Net Core the concept of application [Configuration in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) has been overhauled. Use of `app.Config` is no longer encouraged, even though there are workarounds as explored here [Using app.config in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45034007/1690217).

> **[Adding configuration to windows forms on .NET 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65675178/1690217)**

The basic guidance now is based on use of appsettings.json and hosting environment variables. The new `IConfiguration` supports many different [configuration providers and patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers) which allows us a unified code experience that is no longer dependant on a specific implementation.

Use app.config in .Net solutions had a number of limitations that caused issues with team collaboration through source code repositories but also when implementing CI/CD. It also encouraged poor security practises by embedding secrets directly within the source code. While security is still a key concern, the new architecture encourages the use of externally secured configuration, secrets files and vaults that decouple the runtime and hosting configuration from the development and design-time configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As Guru Stron said, the project shown in the second picture is WinForms (.Net Framework). The first image shows .Net based Winforms, starting with .NET 5, .NET based projects use the appsettings.json file (if you want to configure it, you need to add it to the project) to replace the app.config file.

Regarding the role of App.Config, you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/modernize#appconfig

For detailed information about appsettings.json, you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/configuration/appsettings.json

The main difference between app.config and appsettings.json is the format in which they store data. app.config uses XML format, while appsettings.json uses JSON format.
Another difference is that app.config is specific to the .NET Framework, while appsettings.json is for .NET Core applications. You also get web.config, which is specifically for .NET Framework web-based applications.

I also found a post on SO that you might be interested in: [App.config deprecated C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141969/app-config-deprecated-c)