# When you change a string resource, what's the minimum that needs to be deployed?

Tags: asp.net, .net

Recently I fixed a typo in a .resx file. Compiled and put the MyApp.resources.dll in the bin\en folder of our test server, then did an iisreset. The text didn't change. Even decompiled to ensure my change was in there.

So I did a full-blown deployment and then I saw the change. I guess I need to include more than just the resource dll, wondering what, at a minimum, I would need to deploy.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: This is ***NOT*** an answer to your question, but an idea to make things simpler for you.  Instead of using String Resources, we tend to put commonly used, but likely-to-change strings in our app.config (or web.config for ASP.NET) as appSettings.  Or, if we think they'll change often enough to make it wirht it, we'll look up those resources in a database. It's infinitely easier to update a record in a database than deploy code or even a .config file.  Also, related to your question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460935/pros-and-cons-of-appsettings-vs-applicationsettings-net-app-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because ASP.NET keeps using the DLLs cached in "Temporary asp.net files" folder.

Cleaning that folder should help. Also, "touching" the main project DLL will cause IIS/ASP.NET to pick up the files from the "bin" folder and update the "temporary" ones.

```
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vXXXXXXX\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
```