# C# getting value from app.config

Tags: c#

Is it possible to read the setting value URL using `ConfigurationManager` ?
I'm trying to read this section, but all I get it's null values. I could parse it using XmlDocument... I have already looked for this question within this forum but all I get is ways to get connectionstring, which is quite easy since ConfigurationManager has a ConnectionString Method.

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <ProjectoGlobal.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ProjectoGlobal_WebServicePg_SyncPgData" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost/SarfWebService/SyncPgData.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </ProjectoGlobal.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can access it using:

`Properties.Settings.Default.ProjectoGlobal_WebServicePg_SyncPgData`

Here's `MSDN` reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Thanks for all -1's ;)

Comment: That definitely works... But it's not with configurationManager.. Thanks

Comment: @Nuno it's not the same thing... take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460935/pros-and-cons-of-appsettings-vs-applicationsettings-net-app-config

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do:

```
string setting = yourprojectname.Properties.Settings.Default.ProjectoGlobal_WebServicePg_SyncPgData;
```

EDIT:

ok using the configuration manager just for demonstration purposes:

```
Configuration conf;

this.conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

ConfigurationSectionGroup sectionGroup = this.conf.GetSectionGroup("applicationSettings");

ClientSettingsSection section =
(ClientSettingsSection)sectionGroup.Sections.Get("ProjectoGlobal.Properties.Settings");

SettingElement setting = section.Settings.Get("ProjectoGlobal_WebServicePg_SyncPgData");

string result = setting.Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
```

you should use the first option though...

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myHttpString" value="http://localhost/SarfWebService/SyncPgData.asmx" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Documentation: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)