# unable to retrieve value from app.config

Tags: vb.net, app-config, configurationmanager

### Issue

---

I just want to be able to retrieve a value inside my App.Config file but it just does not seem to work.

The code to retrieve the value is:

```
Dim email As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("stmpFromEmail")
```

My App.Config:

```
<configuration>
    <applicationSettings>
        <DataImport.DataImport.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="stmpFromEmail" serializeAs="String">
                <value>AgilityDataImport@agilitylogistics.com</value>
            </setting>
        </DataImport.DataImport.My.MySettings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I cannot seem to get the value back, help anyone?

Comment: appSetting and applicationSettings are two different sections. See [Pros and cons of appSettings vs applicationSettings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460935/pros-and-cons-of-appsettings-vs-applicationsettings-net-app-config)

Comment: is there a reason you are using applicationSettings vs appSetting ?

Comment: @coder32 No not really what do i need to change to get it to work?

Comment: okay, then do the below

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you would have to change your app.config file to be like the below.

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>                               
<add key="stmpFromEmail" value="AgilityDataImport@agilitylogistics.com"/> 
<appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can call it like the below.

```
Dim email As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("stmpFromEmail")
```