# C# getting the path of %AppData%

Tags: c#, .net, path

C# 2008 SP1

I am using the code below:

```
dt.ReadXml("%AppData%\\DateLinks.xml");
```

However, I am getting an exception that points to the location of where my application is running from:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'D:\Projects\SubVersionProjects\CatDialer\bin\Debug\%AppData%\DateLinks.xml'.

I thought the `%AppData%` should find the relative path. When I go `Start|Run|%AppData%` windows explorer takes me to that directory.

I can not put the full path in, as the user is different on each client machine.

Answer (score 993, accepted):

To get the *AppData* directory, it's best to use the `GetFolderPath` method:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

(must add `using System` if not present).

`%AppData%` is an environment variable, and they are not automatically expanded anywhere in .NET, although you can explicitly use the [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables) method to do so. I would still strongly suggest that you use `GetFolderPath` however, because as Johannes Rössel points out in the comment, `%AppData%` may not be set in certain circumstances.

Finally, to create the path as shown in your example:

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "DateLinks.xml");
```

Comment: +1 for offering a real solution, not relying on the environment. To add to the answer: Not every function that handles file names expands environment variables. In fact, usually you have to explicitly do this, otherwise it doesn't work and you'll end up with %something% folders. Furthermore, the environment does not need to be present, in some cases when running a program under another user account the user's environment will not be loaded and %Appdata% will be empty. That's why you would want to use the documented APIs for getting those folders (unless you're using batch files, though).

Comment: @Johannes: Good info there. I just amended my answer as you posted that, but I'll make it clearer that GetFolderPath is definitely preferable over ExpandEnvironmentVariable.

Comment: +1 for Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), I was behind this for couple of days now.

Comment: For some reason `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` returns empty string for me (IIS 7, VS 2011). Problem solved using Simon_Weaver solution - mapping using `MapPath`.

Comment: FYI that gives the Roaming directory for local AppData Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)

Comment: Thank you for the link to `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariable`.  Certainly it's better to use GetFolderPath where possible, but there can be legitimate reasons to use the `%` form, such as when the value is in a config file.

Comment: In Linux Docker containers, `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` usually returns empty string because the folder does not exist. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create)` creates the folder and returns the path (e.g. `/root/.config`).

Answer (score 87):

The **BEST** way to use the AppData directory, **IS** to use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) method.

**Reasons:**

- it replaces parts of your string with valid directories or whatever
- it is case-insensitive
- it is easy and uncomplicated
- it is a standard
- good for dealing with user input

**Examples:**

```
string path;
path = @"%AppData%\stuff";
path = @"%aPpdAtA%\HelloWorld";
path = @"%progRAMfiLES%\Adobe;%appdata%\FileZilla"; // collection of paths

path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

**[More info:](https://www.askvg.com/list-of-environment-variables-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/)**

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%   C:\ProgramData
%APPDATA%   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%    C:\Program Files\Common Files
%COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)%   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
%COMSPEC%   C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
%HOMEDRIVE% C:
%HOMEPATH%  C:\Users\Username
%LOCALAPPDATA%  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local
%PROGRAMDATA%   C:\ProgramData
%PROGRAMFILES%  C:\Program Files
%PROGRAMFILES(X86)% C:\Program Files (x86) (only in 64-bit version)
%PUBLIC%    C:\Users\Public
%SystemDrive%   C:
%SystemRoot%    C:\Windows
%TEMP% and %TMP%    C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp
%USERPROFILE%   C:\Users\Username
%WINDIR%    C:\Windows
```

Comment: Liked your examples of `path` variable :)

Comment: +1 `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariable` is best when you simply need to expand regardless of which env vars might be in the path string.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question that was asked. This needs to be higher up

Comment: This does not work on Unix.

Answer (score 51):

The path is different if you're talking ASP.NET.

I couldn't find any of the 'SpecialFolder' values that pointed to /App_Data for ASP.NET.

Instead you need to do this:

```
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data")
```

(Note: You don't need the 'Current' property in an MVC Controller)

If theres another more 'abstract' way to get to `App_Data` would love to hear how.

Comment: Just a note since asp.net core is coming out now. This approach relies specifically on IIS.

Comment: `HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data")` is better and works in both MVC / WebAPI and WCF contexts where there is no HttpContext - but not sure about core'

Answer (score 27):

You can also use

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\DateLinks.xml");
```

to expand the `%AppData%` variable.

Comment: The function `ExpandEnvironmentVariables` was new to me, thanks for mention that!

Answer (score 15):

In .net2.0 you can use the variable `Application.UserAppDataPath`

Comment: That only works with Windows Forms.

Answer (score 15):

**AppData ⇝ Local** aka (`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local`):

```cs
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

---

**AppData ⇝ Roaming** aka (`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming`):

```cs
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

---

Additionally, it could be handy to know:

- `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles`    - for Program files X64 folder
- `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86` - for Program files X86 folder

For the full list check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 6):

I don't think putting %AppData% in a string like that will work.

try

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).ToString()
```

Comment: Why the `ToString`? It's already giving you a string...

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to share another way of accessing 'App_Data' folder in my mvc application in case that someone needs this.

```
 Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,"App_Data")
```

Comment: Might not be the right answer, but it is what i was looking for. +1

Comment: Worked for me after replacing single quotes with double quotes. Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath,"App_Data")

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET, the `Load User Profile` setting needs to be set on the app pool but that's not enough. There is a hidden setting named `setProfileEnvironment` in `\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config`, which for some reason is turned off by default, instead of on as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel). You can either change the default or set it on your app pool. All the methods on the `Environment` class will then return proper values.

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in a console application -

```
string appData = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA");
```

Comment: This is not going to work on Unix.