# Connecting with ms acess database on ftp server using oledb connection string

Tags: asp-classic, ftp, oledbconnection

Could You tell me how can I connect with my ms access database on my ftp server ?. I'am using this connection string:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=ftp://ftp.myAccount.pl/myAccount.pl/dataBase/file.mdb; User Id=myUserName; Password=myPassword";
        con.Open();
```

but wont work :(.

Comment: I don't believe ftp is a supported transaport/scheme in data source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374464/connection-string-for-ms-access-database  you can only use local or mapped diskdrives or unc paths

Comment: Thank You very much for answer. I will try to figure out something with that.

Comment: Access is a flat file database, rather than client server.  It needs to be either on your server itself or a networked drive.  FTP stands for file transfer protocol.  It's purely for copying files from a local drive to a remote location, and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: http://www.zbconsulting.eu/?tabid=58

Contains a working demo too.