# How to store xml / settings inside User's directory

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

This is a pretty simple and easy question: How do I store and use file inside User's AppData directory?

I'm making a simple multimedia player and I want to store my library.xml file somewhere on the user's computer.

I'd also like to know how to use them, for example if I want to use my library.xml file with FileStream how do I make a reference to it?

```
ReadFileStream = new FileStream(@"\WHERE-IS-IT\Library.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

Comment: "C# / .NET" wasn't necessary in the title. We've got tags for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Take a look at this previous answer: [C# getting the path of %AppData%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-getting-the-path-of-appdata/867493#867493)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helps a lot! Is there any MSDN page about how to store settings file, etc? Do I have to create a directory and the files on the first start of the application? Thanks again.

Comment: You should definitely create your own directory... usually the convention is `(AppData)/Company/Product/`.  What you do in there is totally up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in .NET. It takes care of the location and security per windows flavour. [isolatedstoragefile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx) can be used to manange files and directories. [isolatedstoragefilestream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.aspx) can be used to access files.