# Client specific setting in app configuration after clickonce published application

Tags: winforms, configuration, clickonce

I have one windows form application which can be installed per user basis.I am using Sql express in my application as database and also using entity framework to handle my data access side.I have one App configuration file in application which purpose is allow to my clients to give the value of some keys as per their convenient.Like image folder path, the path for my custom log file which will record the exceptions of application during production use,connection strings of entity framework etc.

Now I have used clickonce deployement to get the my software installation at each client machine.After installation at one of my client machine(which is my test environment)I did not see any config and on many search I came to know it is created deep inside some special folder as per OS being used and also these deep buried configuration file can not be modified becuase of some clickonce security provisions.Now I have below questions-

1. Since I can not publish application for per user so how can I chnage the settings for my each individual user after installing the application at client machine.
2. Should I reffer the some external config source but how and where I can put this in Machine. and If externl config works ,can it also be use for entity framework connection string.
3. How to persist these client specific changes.

since I am new in clickonce and I did serach at google but could not get the solution.So any guidence will be highly appreciated in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `App.Config` stores settings at an Application level rather than at User level.

I am not 100% sure from your post but if you want to store settings for each individual user then the best place is probably APPDATA directory.

You can access the APPDATA path using this call:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

You can find out more about APPDATA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata).