# Is it possible to use a path with %% in it?

Tags: c#, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# getting the path of %AppData%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata)

I am trying to use `StreamReader` to open up a path in the form of `%appdata%/folder/file.txt`.  All my attempts have ended up in a file not found exception.  Is there a way I can open up this type of path or otherwise determine the actual location that it points to?

Comment: If i were trying to debug this, I would try to write a file to %appdata%/myFile.txt  and then search my c: drive to see if the file was generated, and if it was, where.

Comment: and here's a suggestion.  when asking questions, you shouldn't ask `"is it possible to do X"`  you should ask `"How do I do X"`  I'd edit your title to follow that convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/folder/file.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET .instead of using %appdata% use [System.Environment.SpecialFolders.ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```