# Renaming a file in %appdata% in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

So I need somone to tell me how to fix this code. I'm trying to rename a file which is in `C:\%appdata%\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\XenonUpdate.jar` to `minecraft.jar`.
The code I am using is:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\%appdata%\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\XenonUpdate.jar", "minecraft.jar")
```

Can someone fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%appdata%` not not a valid path, rather it denotes a special folder that you can get by using `Environment.GetFolderPath`, once a get the `%appdata%` path, you can easily rename file.

```
    Dim folder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    Dim file_to_rename = Path.Combine(folder, ".minecraft\bin\XenonUpdate.jar")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(file_to_rename, "minecraft.jar")
```

Answer (score 0):

File handling functions do not deal with environment variable expansion, `%appdata%`.  You need to do this yourself.

My VB.Net is non-existent, but I think it would look like

```
Dim path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
Dim from = path + "\.minecraft..."
Dim to = path + "\.minecraft..."
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(from, to)
```

Also, see [C# getting the path of %AppData%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata)