# Read content of %APPDATA%

Tags: c#

If I type `%APPDATA%\Skype` into Windows Explorer then Windows Explorer shows me the content of `C:\Users\Stevew\AppData\Roaming\Skype`.

But if I do this in C#

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"%APPDATA%\Skype");
```

then I get an exception saying `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\Stevew\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\TestSkype\\TestResults\\Stevew_PC 2014-05-29 15_45_30\\Out\\%APPDATA%\\Skype'`.

I suppose the `%APPDATA%`-part was not parsed. How can read the content of `C:\Users\Stevew\AppData\Roaming\Skype` using this syntax?

I know about `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`, but I want to use the `%SOMETHING%`-syntax in this case, I want to be able to use any of the environment variables. I've tried to search, but I don't really know what to search for.

Comment: %APPDATA% is a windows shell thing. The .NET library won't know this syntax.

Comment: Have a look at [C# getting the path of %AppData%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty The OP posted that he doesn't want to use that syntax.

``Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)``

Comment: @abhi: I didn't answer the question!!! This is a comment, since is lead user to right path, I mean to use `Environment.GetFolderPath`

Comment: try this: string AppData = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%APPDATA%\Skype");
```

should return the desired value.