# c# file writing privileges - xml serialization vs file move/copy

Tags: c#

I recently used XML Serializer to serliaze an object in one of my apps and after looking around a bit online i figured it requires the software to be started with admin privs.

Now I got around to doing something else which copies/moves/modifies files on the hard drive and it does NOT require any admin privs

Is there a way to use the xml serialization without admin privs also? 
Whats the difference between the two?

Thanks

Comment: XML De/Serialization requires no special permissions, maybe you tried to write the output of the serialization process to a Program Files-related folder? Try AppData like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped