# Get and set clipboard contents regardless of format - C#

Tags: .net, clipboard

In .NET, is it possible to get the clipboard contents regardless of format, hold them in memory and then later restore them?

I tried `Clipboard.GetDataObject()` but it seems impossible to restore this value without knowing the format. I would ideally like to:

```
var list = new List<object>();
...
list.Add(Clipboard.GetData());
... later ...
Clipboard.SetData(list[x]);
```

Comment: Cant you call GetDataObject and to set the data, loop through all objects using the format list and call SetData multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible because of one reason: you just don't know what user will put in clipboard during activity. The only way is to try which format of data is in cliboard using [DataFormats Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.aspx)

Comment: That's a shame. A appreciate I would need to know the format to use/interact with the data, but just to store it for a few minutes and then restore it to the clipboard?

Comment: Why you don't store data on disk? You could use app data folder(see more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata) Also temp folder should be a good idea.