# Error with HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()

Tags: c#, server.mappath

I'm using this code as part of class which should connect to an Access database:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data");
```

The App_Data folder is in the project, and contains the database, but somehow the `MapPath()` returns `null`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata

Comment: Try to pass the *relative* name, "/App_Data" or "~/App_Data".

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
string folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null ?
            System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_data") :
            System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```