# Where do the files that normally get saved in bin\Debug get saved when the published application is run?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

When run in Visual Studio 2017 debug mode, my C# WPF application saves output files to the bin\Debug folder.

I have now published my application via the Publish Wizard and can run it standalone from the Start menu. Where (if anywhere) are the output files being saved?

Comment: right click on application in Start Menu, select more , select open file location

Comment: There are a number of deployment options that use the word "Publish".  The answer here depends on exactly what you chose.

Comment: Its gonna save it in C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ if you used the default publish option with ClickOnce

Comment: Published to C: using wizard "From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM" and "The application will not check for updates". Right clicking on the start menu takes me to C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyApp. The output files are nowhere to be seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will usually save them in

```
C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\
```

Comment: Not in there either sorry

Comment: Actually you were right, the files were buried under C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\P95GG51P.EN7\3OGPD47T.JGR\pipe..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_fa2d6a4be4f2779b

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is sort of an X Y problem. Instead of trying to locate the output files depending on publishing scheme, your program should try to be deterministic about where it places its output. Set up a path variable in your program and place the output there. See the answer to this question on how to do that: [C# getting the path of %AppData%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata)

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed what I am now doing to resolve it.