# connectionstring to Access sql localDB in appdata folder

Tags: connection-string, localdb, setup-deployment

i have a winform application with `SQL localDB`  and i used `advanced installer` to deploy it, but once deployed in my target machine inside `C:Programme files` , i get an error when i tried to update my database that say : `Database read-only` and that is because the folder deployed in does not give permission to the user to write in it.

So, i installed my application in `\user\appdata\roaming` where i have permission to write and it worked !

that's not good, i want to keep my application folder in `C:Progamme files` and copy only mydatabase.mdr in `\user\appdata\roaming`.

but if i do that, i can no longer access my database with my current `connectionstring`, so my question is how can i change my `connectionstring` to access my database inside `\user\appdata\roaming` in any target machine?

this is my connectionstring :

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="GTC_Frater_Razes.Properties.Settings.db_alarmeConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db_alarme.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your connection string cannot use `|DataDirectory|` which is a sort of variable which is expanded to a full path. As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/connection-strings#support-for-the-124datadirectory124-substitution-string-and-the-web-application-root-operator-):

> A path that starts with the `DataDirectory` or the `~` operator cannot resolve to a physical path outside the branch of the `DataDirectory` and the `~` operator.

If the database will be at `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName\db_alarme.mdf`, you can manually set your connection string as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add
    name="GTC_Frater_Razes.Properties.Settings.db_alarmeConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName\db_alarme.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Since apparently you can't use environment variables -- `%APPDATA%` -- you'll have to know the deployment directory ahead of time.

Alternatively, you can set the value of `DataDirectory` using the [**AppDomain.SetData** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c(v=vs.110).aspx) before you actually open the connection:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName");
```

You can get the location of `AppData\Roaming` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/867493/111794); and pass in the combined path to `SetData`.

```
var dataDirectory = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
    "ApplicationName"
);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dataDirectory);
```

Comment: the second one doesn't work and the first one works but i can't use it because i have to put my "UserName", i need the username to be variable so it can works on any target machine

Comment: i don't have to know the deployment directory because in my installer i am going to copy my database in the AppData folder of my target computer, i just want to get a standard connectionstring that works with every username, how can i do that ?

Comment: @lawir I don't think this is possible using `DataDirectory`, which cannot be used to refer to something outside the current folder of the application. AFAIK, `DataDirectory` and `~` are the only variables supported in connection strings; there are no variables for various system and user-profile paths. Did you try using `SetData` in the code before opening any connections? I've updated my answer.

Comment: so the "dataDirectory" get the path and then pass it to "DataDirectory" with AppDomain.SetData ? so where should i put this code ?

Comment: @lawir Before you open any connection to the database.

Comment: i have an error with appdomain.setdata that says : "an object reference is required for a non static field, method or property?  do i miss an assembly?

Comment: @lawir Try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(`

Comment: It is working, with `appDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData` !!!!!! Thank you so much :)