# How to specify username when referencing directory in C#

Tags: c#

Essentially I am trying to create a C# program that goes into a local directory and performs some tasks by executing a batch file. The batch file itself is located in the AppData Roaming table and requires the C# program to know the username of the computer, whatever it may be.

**This is what I currently have:**

```
static void Main()
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Roaming");
    processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    Process batchProcess = new Process();
    batchProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
    batchProcess.Start();
}
```

Notice how I've added %username% but it doesn't seem to understand environmental variables.

What can I add to my code?

My code is not exactly a duplicate as the use case is entirely different, I am referencing the app data roaming directory and opening a batch located in it.

Comment: You wanna get username of your computer?

Comment: Yes, I would for the program to understand what the current logged in username is

Comment: solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c

Comment: The duplicate answers the question, but given the code example there is a better approach to use. I suggest to reopen here

Comment: You probably want to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` instead of building that path yourself.

Comment: @Steve I just submitted a reason why my code is different, I would appreciate your take on the matter

Comment: The comment above from @huysentruitw is all what you need to do. Get the result of that line in a string variable and use it instead of your hard coded path.

Comment: By the way, passing just the directory name to ProcessStartInfo constructor will not execute your batch. You seems to missing something there or in the code below before starting the process.

Comment: To combine the roaming path with your executable name, use `Path.Combine()`

Comment: The way the title is worded, the linked duplicate makes sense, but from what is intended, I would think something like the following would be a more appropriate duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user folder for the current user like this:

```
string userfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

And so the path you want would be like:

```
string path = Path.Combine(userfolder, "AppData\\Roaming");
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
```

Comment: How can I implement this into my path?

Comment: @Winston I edited my answer please have a look

Comment: You know, we can change the roaming folder. This will fail if the roaming folder is no more inside the user folder or if we have a different name. This happens a lot in more sophisticated environments than an home pc.

Comment: How can I use the "path" string, instead of the path given in new ProcessStartInfo?

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: @Steve No, I had no idea, what can be done about this? I need to make sure the appdata roaming folder is always found

Comment: That's the reason to use the appropriate and dedicated _Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData_ instead of building manually what you think should be the roaming folder for the current user. We have told you this 20 minutes ago

Comment: My apologies, this is what I ended up using:

Comment: string userfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string path = Path.Combine(userfolder, "test1.bat");