# Defining LocalAppData for my project is not working as it tries looking for %LOCALAPPDATA% Inside of my project directory

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete something from my local app data, this is my code

```
string folder = "%LOCALAPPDATA%\\test";
Directory.Delete(folder);
```

The error I get is that it's trying to find The `%LOCALAPPDATA%` Path inside of where my project is stored, I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong. If you can please help!

Comment: You need to explicitly [expand environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=net-5.0). Neither a plain string or any file managing function interprets them, unless otherwise noted.

Comment: note that `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\\\test` doesn't refer to the folder test but `tab` followed by `est`. You should use verbatim string instead: `@"%LOCALAPPDATA%\test"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# getting the path of %AppData%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Environment.GetFolderPath to retrieve the location of the LocalAppData folder. Example:

```
var localAppData = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
var testFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(localAppData, "test");
```

Comment: Ok but what if I want to delete the directory that is inside of the localappdata "test" too

Comment: Then `Directory.Delete(testFolder);`.

Comment: This is the error I get when I do that : 


This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int, string)
    System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(string, string, bool, bool, ref Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.WIN32_FIND_DATA)
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(string, string, bool, bool)
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(string)
    File_Cleaner.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs

Comment: Is the directory empty? `Delete` only works with empty directories, if it isn't, you'll have to use the second overload and make it recursive: `Directory.Delete(testFolder, true)`.

Comment: Ah yes okay that works, thank you so much!