# Delete 64-bit registry Key using 32-bit installer

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have installer (InstallanyWhere 2013) that has feature to execute the batch file.
I created the installer using 32 bit JRE.

I have two location:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Lock Configuration Tool (**32 bit registry location**)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Lock Configuration Tool (**64 bit registry location**)

Batch file code:

```
 cd\
cd c:\windows\system32
    reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ProjectName" /f
```

When above command executed then it point to 32 bit registry not the 64 bit registry.
I know the reason the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE" convert to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node so it point to 32 bit registry.

**My question how to delete the 64 bit registry using 32 bit installer (internally use the batch file) via command prompt.** Does command prompt provide any feature to point to 64 bit registry?

Comment: possible duplicate of [32bit application access to 64bit registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712830/32bit-application-access-to-64bit-registry)

Comment: Invoke the 64-bit Cmd Prompt to run the batch file.

Answer (score 5):

This one plagued us for while.  You need to use the /reg:64 parameter. [Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948698)

Example:

```
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ProjectName" /f /reg:64
```