# Deleting Registry Key with Batch Script from Uninstall

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, registry, installshield

I have a batch script that deletes certain registry keys, it works as a script itself and also from the command line. However, as part of an uninstaller (Installshield), one of the 2 registry keys does not delete. My log file indicates that "the operation completed successfully" but for the life of me, the key is still there.

The command looks like this:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ProgramName\SubEntry" /f
```

and my log file:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ProgramName\SubEntry" /f
```

The operation completed successfully.

I can run the batch script itself as an admin and it works, I always run the installer (to install and uninstall) as an admin.

Comment: Is the key still present after logout/login or a reboot?

Comment: Yes, I suspect it has to do with the location since it's being called from a 32-bit application. Even if I'm not specifically calling it, it might be looking in the Wow6432Node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Since the installer is 32-bit, it was looking in the 32-bit entries in the registry (under WOW6432Node). By specifying /reg:64 at the end of my command it deleted the correct entry. I got the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623498/delete-64-bit-registry-key-using-32-bit-installer).