# Python: Writing value to registry

Tags: python, permissions, registry, registrykey

I want to add a script to windows startup by writing a new value to Run registry key. I have the following code in python.

```
from _winreg import *

def setScriptAtStartup(
    value_name,
    bAdd,
    script_path=None
):
'''
:param value_name: the name value to be used in registry
:param bAdd: TRUE = Add, FALSE = Remove
:param script_path: path to run at startup
:return:
'''

if bAdd and script_path == None:
    return False

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)

print r"*** Writing to SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run ***"
try:
    aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE)
    if(bAdd):
        SetValueEx(aKey, value_name, 0, REG_SZ, script_path)
    else:
        DeleteValue(aKey, value_name)
except EnvironmentError:
    print "Encountered problems writing into the Registry..."
CloseKey(aKey)

CloseKey(aReg)

return
```

The problem is that when i call OpenKey function, it always raise *EnvironmentError* and I can't figure it out why. I have checked the path and it is a valid one. Additionaly, I have tried to open only SOFTWARE key and it fails again.

What can i do to fix this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Does reading from the key work ok?

Comment: Are you using 32-bit Python on a 64-bii Windows computer? If so, see [_Cannot Write to the Registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4951064/355230).

Comment: The question's fine because python's error message is bad.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It needs admin privileges to have access to registry.