# How do I connect to the default instance of SQL Server if a "named instance" parameter is required?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I'm installing some software and I need to tell it to use the default instance of SQL Server, however the Installshield GUI insists that I enter in information for a named instance.

The target SQL Server is version 2008R2

I'm hoping there is a clean hack that I can use such as "." or "default" but I haven't guessed it yet.  I've also tried MSSQLSERVER, and that didn't work either.

Comment: The question is old, but I think now I have an answer for you! (see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46238551/1016343)**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All SQL server instances are stored in the [Windows Registry.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) You can query the registry by using the Windows tool `C:\Windows\System32\Regedt32.exe` and browse/search there, you can do it by using a language, like [C#  (see **Example 1** there)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13232372/1016343#Example1) or even T-SQL (also known as Transact-SQL).

In this answer, I'll show you how to do it with **T-SQL**. Use this script, which I found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/eb58a7fe-4647-4eea-91e3-6ee369362d64/how-to-find-instance-name?forum=sqlgetstarted), to determine ServerName, InstanceName, HostName and PortNumber:

```
set nocount on
Declare @key Varchar(100), @PortNumber varchar(20)

if charindex('\',CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('servername')),0) <>0 begin
    set @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Microsoft SQL Server\'+@@servicename+'\MSSQLServer\Supersocketnetlib\TCP'
end else begin
    set @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Supersocketnetlib\TCP'
end

EXEC master..xp_regread @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key = @key, 
     @value_name = 'Tcpport', @value = @PortNumber OUTPUT
SELECT  CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('servername')) ServerName,
        CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')) InstanceName,
        CONVERT(char(20), SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')) as HostName, 
        convert(varchar(10), @PortNumber) PortNumber
```

If the `InstanceName` is `null`, it means there is no named instance configured, then you have two, non-exclusive options:

1. Specify the `ServerName` to access the default instance 
    **- or -**
2. Use the **Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Native Client XX.Y Configuration -> Aliases** to define an alias. For example:
   [image: Define_Alias] 
   will set up alias `Inst1` for the local SQL server. Specify `(local)\Inst1,1433` to access it. Of course, instead of `(local)` you can also use the ServerName.
   **IMPORTANT:** After setting up the alias, you need to restart the SQL service of the related instance or reboot your PC, otherwise it will not be accessible immediately. If you're using a port other than the default port 1433, you might need to open your local firewall in order to get this working.

---

**Note:** If you don't have it in the start menu, the SQL Server Configuration Manager can be found in C:\Windows\System32. Look for SqlServerManagerXX.msc (where XX is the SQL version, e.g. XX=11 or XX=13).

Answer (score 9):

Run this query:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME + '\' + @@SERVICENAME AS InstanceName
```

and use the result as your instance name.

Comment: I tried this to connect to default SQL Server instance through SSMS but it doesn't work. If I simply try `.` or `<machineName>` it works. Query `SELECT @@SERVICENAME AS InstanceName` returns `MSSQLSERVER`. `<machineName>\MSSQLSERVER` doesn't work

Comment: For default  instance this nomenclature doesn't work even from code. It has to be either `.` or `<MachineName>`.

Comment: The instance name created this way is not correct, if no instance name is specified and there is only a default instance on the server.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a default instance configured just use the server hostname as instance

Answer (score 0):

Try `MSSQLSERVER`. That may be the default instance name according to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The setup wizard will take MSSQLSERVER which means "default" instance.

See step 12 in the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx)