# RegistryView.Registry64 returns from the 32 bit view

Tags: c#, registry

```
RegistryKey localMachineRegistry = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,RegistryView.Registry64);
string[] list = localMachineRegistry.GetSubKeyNames();
RegistryKey key = localMachineRegistry.OpenSubKey(keyPath, false);
list = key.GetSubKeyNames();
```

I am on a 64bit OS. The process I am running is 32 bit, but I know the registry setting is in the wow64 area. The call to `localMachineRegistry.GetSubKeyNames()` is returning the 32 bit information, and when I create a key using the wow64 regedit, the call to `localMachineRegistry.OpenSubKey()` returns `null`.

All i can think of is a 32bit process cannot use RegistryView.Registry64 however i have not read that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are correct in that a 32 bit application cannot read from the "64 bit" registry, it will always get the 32 bit copy located in the `Wow6432Node`.  I suspect that this is because technically the 64 bit registry could have data that would not fit in a 32 bit process (i.e. 64 bit DWORDs).

Comment: It's queer that this anwer is still marked as accepted, because it is wrong on many points: 1) reading 64-bit registry is possible from 32-bit process ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13232372/536172)); 2) DWORDs are always 32-bit.