# Getting registry key value in VB.Net where key name has spaces

Tags: registry, vb.net

I am trying to read registry key value in VB.Net with not much luck.
Here is the key in question: 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\Setup and Configuration Software\INTEL-SA-00086 Discovery Tool\System Status`

Here is the code snippet

```
Dim key As String = "SOFTWARE\Intel\Setup And Configuration Software\INTEL-SA-00086 Discovery Tool\System Status"
Dim val As String = "System Risk"
MessageBox.Show(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(key, val, Nothing))
```

So far I've been able to figure out that the issue is spaces between the key names as I can get the value of other keys where name doesn't have spaces.

I've tried escaping registry key path in VB.Net but it is either returning the value name in itself or throwing an exception.

This isn't because of backspace or slashes as the following works

```
Dim key As String = "SOFTWARE\Intel\PSIS\PSIS_DECODER"
Dim val As String = "SomeKey"
MessageBox.Show(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(key, val, Nothing))
```

This doesn't work when **val** has space in between the value name

```
Dim key As String = "SOFTWARE\Intel\PSIS\PSIS_DECODER"
Dim val As String = "Some Key"
MessageBox.Show(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(key, val, Nothing))
```

Have seen [enough Microsoft examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) and searched enough forums to find no help. Last attempt here before I look for alternatives

Any magic ?

**Additional Information:**

Here is a snippet which shows that the script returns nothing if there is a space in key name or value.

Here is a key with space in name
[image: Key with space in name]

Returns nothing

[image: Returns nothing]

Comment: This isn't big enough for stackoverflow and superuser gets mixed crowd, so posted here. And I can certainly say the problem isn't backspace or backslash

Comment: Well the same stuff with a different key path works for me. not sure why you think it will work. Test and make it work. I will put this up for bounty

Comment: @Ramhound You think it would work but it doesn't. I have been meddling with this for a while now and it hasn't worked. let me add more details in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69510/discussion-between-pun-and-ramhound).

Comment: AFAIK, keys can have spaces, values cannot

Comment: @Yorik Doesn't work like that. They can have spaces or even special characters depending on what kind of registry value you are talking about

Comment: Open up `regedit` and right-click both key with or without blanks and choose `Permissions` - perhaps the permissions of the key with blanks are stricter.

Comment: @harrymc nahhh it is not permissions

Comment: Which error are you getting? Are you sure that the key doesn't have a hidden character such as a blank at the end? Otherwise there is no possible explanation except a bug in VBS, and that seems very unlikely.

Comment: @harrymc I am not getting any error. It is just that if the key or key value has space in it, it returns nothing. Here are the screenshots that might explain a bit more. https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5MxG.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq7Rp.png

Comment: Try to set your VS project to "any cpu" in advanced compile options - avoid running in x86 on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: @harrymc sadly, I always complie my vs projects for any cpu. I've tried doing otherwise as well

Comment: @harrymc Current system where I am posting from is 1703 but have tried this on other Windows 10's as well. Using community edition on VS and this application is compiled for .Net 4.0    Also if you see the first snippet I posted with my question, I have used what you are suggesting and it does return me the same result.

Comment: Microsoft .NET Framework is now at version 4.5 - worth trying. Do my other links pertain to your case ?

Comment: @harrymc Solution 4 from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/675355/Read-Bit-Registry-Values-Using-VB-NET) worked. Post it as an answer and I will mark it as an answer

Comment: Will do that in 48 hours when I'm back. Glad that your problem is now solved.

Comment: @harrymc I am about to go out on holiday, if you can post an answer before I turn myself into a nomad, it would be nice

Comment: Done the best I could from my own nomad phone. Will improve later.

Comment: Done here too. Not sure why does VB suddenly realizes that we are trying to read a 64bit registry value as soon as a space in involved in the key name or value name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to reading from the 64-bit registry.

As found in
[Read 64-Bit Registry Values Using VB.Net](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/675355/Read-Bit-Registry-Values-Using-VB-NET),
the solution which worked for the poster was:

> use this Format to Read 64-Bit Registry values :
>
> ```
> Dim rk1 As RegistryKey
> Dim rk2 As RegistryKey
> rk1 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
> rk2 = rk1.OpenSubKey("HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS")
> Dim PID As String = rk2.GetValue("SystemProductName").ToString
> ```

More information and solutions can be found here :

- [Read 64-Bit Registry Values Using VB.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/675355/Read-Bit-Registry-Values-Using-VB-NET)
- [Visual Basic.net. Trying to read registry key is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821014/visual-basic-net-trying-to-read-registry-key-is-not-working)