# Registry.GetValue() returns null in x86 configuration, works in x64

Tags: c#

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

...


  string keyname = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\[REST_OF_PATH]
  string value = "ServiceAddress";
  string default = "";
  string stringValue = (string)Registry.GetValue(keyname, value, default);
```

On my x64 machine, this works fine (on my x64 machine) when I build with x64 or AnyCPU, but `stringValue` is `null` when built with an x86 configuration.

I get similar results when I call `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey`

Is it possible to get this to work with an x86 build?

Comment: Well, show the OpenSubKey() code, that's the one that should solve it.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974038/reading-64bit-registry-from-a-32bit-application), it might help.

Answer (score 2):

The 32-bit registry is stored under Wow6432Node. You have probably created your key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE directly, which is the 64-bit portion of the registry. The [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) handles redirecting registry operations performed by 32-bit applications.

If you wish to access the 64-bit portion of the registry from a 32-bit application, you need to pass the flag `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` (`0x0100`) along with your access permissions when opening the key.