# Reading registry keys from c#

Tags: c#, outlook, registry, outlook-addin

I'm trying to fetch some data on the Office Click-To-Run currently installed.

I've read these posts : [Can't Read Registry Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299421/cant-read-registry-key?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [OpenSubKey() returns null for a registry key that I can see in regedit.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728491/opensubkey-returns-null-for-a-registry-key-that-i-can-see-in-regedit-exe)
I'm on Windows 10 64bit. My application is an Outlook add-in, so I can't change the target platform (32/64bit), it's the Host that determine if I'm running in 32bit or 64bit. So I've to handle both cases.

So I've this (test) code :

```
using (var hklmTest64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
    var test = hklmTest64.GetValue(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration\AudienceData");
    if (test == null)
    {
        using (var hklmTest32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32))
        {
            test = hklmTest32.GetValue(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration\AudienceData");
        }
    }
}
```

So I first fetch the registry key using the 64bit view, then if null I retry using the 32bit view.

Problem: test is always `NULL`.
Of course the key exists and I can see it using regedit:

[image: Registry Key visible with regedit]

Of course I first tried simple code that until now always worked for me, but doesn't work to fetch this key:

```
test = Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration\AudienceData");
test = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration", "AudienceData", null);
```

And more strange thing, it's that I had exactly the same problem for fetching the windows build number. This code was not working :

```
var wBuild = Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ReleaseId");
```

But this one works perfectly for windows build (not for outlook key):

```
var wBuild = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ReleaseId", null);
```

Any idea how to fetch this registry key ?

**UPDATE 1**

See the post [C# get Office ClickToRun Registry Key returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062835/c-sharp-get-office-clicktorun-registry-key-returns-null)
But reading the post, my code using `RegistryView.RegistryXX` should work...

**UPDATE 2**

I've reprod the problem using LinqPad, so this is not due to the Outlook host / add-in. I tried to reprod in a .NET Fiddle but indeed the code is not allowed to access the registry :)

I can get the correct values using P/Invoke like explained [in this article](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/). So for me it's clearly a 32/64bit (wow6432node) problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the correct values using P/Invoke like explained in this article. So for me it's clearly a 32/64bit (wow6432node) problem.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need

```
RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey
```

just use `Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, defualt value)`

this is working example

`string InstallPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\" + path, "ActivationCode", null);`

Comment: Of course I started with this simple line and it doesn't work... I'll edit my question to add this info