# What is wrong with getting the registry in C# on Windows 2012 R2 Terminal Server

Tags: c#, registry, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to get the registry value with the following piece of code

```
object key_10 = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\InstallRoot", "Path", null);
```

Generally it works but when I run it on Windows Server 2012 R2 Terminal I get a null value.
I have local administrator rights.
The value exists in the registry (checked with regedit.exe)
.NET Framework is 4.5

Comment: You can't see that key when your program is forced to run in 32-bit mode.  Google "registry redirector" to learn more.  Remove the jitter forcing or use RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() so you can specify the view.

Answer (score 0):

If it returns null, set your build architecture to Any CPU. The operating system may virtualize 32-bit and 64-bit registries differently.
Reference:
[reading-64bit-registry-from-a-32bit-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974038/reading-64bit-registry-from-a-32bit-application)