# C# Winform Registry set and get functions appear to work, but don't actually change the registry

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I'm trying to use this registry hack I found online:

```
;Disables F1 key - Help and Support - in Windows 10
;Ramesh Srinivasan, Winhelponline.com

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win32]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win64]
@=""
```

When I run it as a .reg command via Windows Explorer and watch the registry with regedit, it works as intended. Removing it is another registry file that simply removes the \0 subkey (and win32 and 64 with it). I'm trying to emulate this function with C# in a Winform using .net CORE:

```
        private void CheckF1()
        {
            // Registry data from ;Ramesh Srinivasan, Winhelponline.com
            RegistryKey F1key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0");

            // EGADS! It's active!
            if (F1key == null)
            {
                fckF1RestoreBtn.Enabled = false;
                fckF1KillBtn.Enabled = true;
                fckF1Status.Text = "That creepy bugger is waiting and watching.";
            }
            else
            {
                fckF1RestoreBtn.Enabled = true;
                fckF1KillBtn.Enabled = false;
                fckF1Status.Text = "The F1-Help function had been put in it's place.";
            }
        }

        private void fckF1KillBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win32");
            Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win64");
            CheckF1();
        }

        private void fckF1RestoreBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0");
            CheckF1();
        }
```

Weirdly the code "sees" a setting and responds like it should. Even to the point that whichever toggle position it was in on close it remembers when I load the file again. It's almost like it's playing along to screw with me. Regardless, when I watch the registry, none of my code has any actual effect though by all appearances it seems to work otherwise (it doesn't actually of course because the registry change isn't happening).

NOTE: I have already updated my manifest file for the project to include elevated permissions:

```
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

Here's the breakpoint on the test statement to see if the subkeys are there that shows they are:
[image]

Meanwhile the registry location for the exact path shown in the debug doesn't have the 1.0\0 path at all:
[image]

I don't know how the code is reading phantom values. Someone closed my previous question pointing to another answer that didn't have any effect ([Registry key deleted but still getting value from registry c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458554/registry-key-deleted-but-still-getting-value-from-registry-c-sharp)):

- "Prefer 32 bit" was never checked for my project in the first place
- Modifying my code as recommended had no effect

```
            var key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64)
                    .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\TypeLib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0");
```

- Adding "Wow64Node" to the path makes no difference in execution.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**

Checking to see if the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0 path is present should return null if the \0 path is not present

Adding and removing the subkeys should show in the registry

Comment: Try with `using` blocks on the `RegistryKey` objects, perhaps it's not flushing the changes. You should have `using` anyway

Comment: None of the examples or questions on SO use using blocks, but I tried anyway. It made no difference. That said, I don't know much about the "using" statement so maybe I did it wrong. I just wrote "using ( {the previous line} )". If that's right then it didn't make a difference. If that's wrong, what's the right way to do it? Just using { ALLTHETHINGS } ?

Comment: `using(RegistryKey F1key = .....) { ..... }` and `using(Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(......)) { }`

Comment: I bet it's the [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector)

Comment: You didn't say what is the target CPU of your Project. Is it AnyCPU or something else? -- You don't need elevated permissions to modify the Registry in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` branch. -- The code you posted, in `fckF1KillBtn_Click()`, works as intended.

Comment: Are you folks saying there are two registries, but I'm only able to see one of them in Regedit?

Comment: @Charlieface, ok, done, but no difference

Comment: I tested setting a value on the new keys and was able to find where it's setting and removing as: Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-931048790-1435080534-1961099684-1001\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win32      why? And how do I stop it?

Comment: Which user are you executing this under? If it is a service, check the settings. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is a redirect to `HKEY_USERS` for whichever user is currently logged in (at least as far as that app is concerned).

Comment: Try the following in Powershell `[ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=S-1-5-21-931048790-1435080534-1961099684-1001>"` that should tell you which user

Comment: Apparently it works except that I have two problems: the registry doesn't update automatically and I have to click around or type the subkey manually to see the changes. Also, because I'm running as admin, the values aren't visible unless I'm running regedit as admin. Also, that's not the user I want this for so... I'm kind of out of luck and will have to try something else.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently HKEY_CURRENT_USERS is an alias. When the above code runs, it updates in HKEY_USERS under the specific logged in user. There's a question that talks about this behavior here: [write registry to hkey_current_user instead of hkey_users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261491/write-registry-to-hkey-current-user-instead-of-hkey-users)

That said, the code appears to work, it's just that the registry doesn't update HKCU like when you run .reg commands. To verify it was working, I'd run the toggle that kills the keys then click them in Regedit and it would say they didn't exist. When I toggled back, I could click on them. So basically, it works (not sure if it required the "using" blocks as others suggested, but I see no reason to take them out).

Now my problem is that it points to the admin user and NOT the regular user because I'm running it and regedit as admin. It took forever to determine this based on running regedit as user in one case and admin in another. Bottom line, this won't work and I'll probably end up running .reg files in the command line instead.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USERS` is related to the current logged in User. If you impersonate a different User, this reflects on the Registry branch that is affected. As mentioned, you don't need elevation to write to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USERS` branch: unless otherwise specified (some keys may have different restrictions), the current User has access to it. If you impersonate a different User, that's where your changes are reflected. Then, there's the application's bitness, which you still have not specified.