# Session_Start and ASP.Net Async SessionState Module

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-state, httpcontext, global-asax

We recently integrated the [ASP.Net Async SessionState Module](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/29/introducing-the-asp-net-async-sessionstate-module/) and have started seeing null ref exceptions in our Global.asax Session_Start event handler.

I can't replicate it locally, and it doesn't appear to happen all the time in live, but I believe this is when we attempt to access HttpContext.Current in Session_Start. My guess is HttpContext.Current is sometimes null, because Session initialization is asynchronous.

Any suggestions as to how to address?

Comment: did you implement your own `SessionStateStoreProviderAsyncBase`? if so, can you post some code? also, this package looks to work with HttpContextBase, not HttpContext

Comment: @user326608 no we used the module linked in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the answer is too simple, but I have also seen this from time to time, and I'd suggest that you safeguard your code inside the `Session_Start` event like

```
if (HttpContext.Current !== null)
{
    // do your actions with the Current object
}
else
{
    // possibly add some logging here to see what's going on
}
```

If you notice it is just a race condition, your code will react properly and not just end up in a NullReferenceException.

Safeguarding it like this is in this particular case better than adding Elvis operators (`?.`) everywhere you're referencing it because that will lead into more complex scenarios for your testing/troubleshooting. In other cases, however, this operator is quite useful, for example in this [different context.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13232372/1016343)

Additionally, In [the link you provided,](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/29/introducing-the-asp-net-async-sessionstate-module/) I saw the hint *"To implement your own async sessionstate provider which works with Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, all you need to do is to implement a concrete SessionStateStoreProviderAsyncBase class which is included in the Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule NuGet package."*

Maybe you just need to implement that class rather than using Session_Start - because here is always a HttpContext given as parameter and Session_Start is just there for backwards-compatibility?

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I have done. Unfortunately we need to HttpContext to perform some business logic

Comment: In the link you provided, I saw the hint *"To implement your own async sessionstate provider which works with Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, all you need to do is to implement a concrete SessionStateStoreProviderAsyncBase class which is included in the Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule NuGet package."* - just a guess: Maybe you just need to implement that class rather than using Session_Start - because here is always a HttpContext given as parameter and Session_Start is just there for backwards-compatibility?

Comment: Interesting idea. That may be worth exploring. I'll have a look