# Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey() returns a result different from Registry Editor

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to Create an installer for my CAD plugin, and need to get the AutoCAD install location. but the return values of `RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames()` is different from what I see in Registry Editor.

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
{
    foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(subkey_name);
    }
}
```

output:

> AddressBook
>   Autodesk Application Manager
>   Autodesk Content Service
>   Autodesk Material Library 2015
>   Autodesk Material Library Base Resolution Image Library 2015
>   Connection Manager
>   DirectDrawEx
>   DXM_Runtime
>   f528b707
>   Fontcore
>   ...

In Registry Editor:

> animizvideocn_is1
>   AutoCAD 2015
>   Autodesk 360
>   Connection Manager
>   ...

`AutoCAD 2015` is what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your installer seems to be a 32 bit application, or at least runs as a 32 bit process.

Therefore, Windows redirects

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

To access the non redirected node, follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974038/reading-64bit-registry-from-a-32bit-application).

Comment: Thank you, Heinz Kessler, that helps a lot ! after replacing `Registry.LocalMachine` with `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)`, I finally got *AutoCAD 2015* in the return values.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not a direct answer to your question, but i had to do the same thing. I was not looking at the registry, but the Program Files directory. It will then add the netload command to the autoload lisp file. It will install a list of Plugin dlls to all installed autocad versions. This can easily be changed... Hopefully it helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace AMU.AutoCAD.Update
{
  public class AutoCadPluginInstaller
  {
    private static readonly Regex AutoloadFilenameRegex = new Regex("acad([\\d])*.lsp");

    public void Install(IEnumerable<string> pluginFiles)
    {
      var acadDirs = this.GetAcadInstallationPaths();
      var autoloadFiles = acadDirs.Select(this.GetAutoloadFile);

      foreach (var autoloadFile in autoloadFiles)
        this.InstallIntoAutoloadFile(autoloadFile, pluginFiles);
    }

    private void InstallIntoAutoloadFile(string autoloadFile, IEnumerable<string> pluginFiles)
    {
      try
      {
        var content = File.ReadAllLines(autoloadFile).ToList();
        foreach (var pluginFile in pluginFiles)
        {
          var loadLine = this.BuildLoadLine(pluginFile);
          if(!content.Contains(loadLine))
            content.Add(loadLine);
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(autoloadFile, content);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        //log.Log();
      }
    }

    private string BuildLoadLine(string pluginFile)
    {
      pluginFile = pluginFile.Replace(@"\", "/");
      return $"(command \"_netload\" \"{pluginFile}\")";
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetAcadInstallationPaths()
    {
      var programDirs =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);

      var autoDeskDir = Path.Combine(programDirs, "Autodesk");
      if (!Directory.Exists(autoDeskDir))
        return null;

      return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(autoDeskDir)
                             .Where(d => d.Contains("AutoCAD"));
    }

    private string GetAutoloadFile(string acadDir)
    {
      var supportDir = Path.Combine(acadDir, "Support");
      var supportFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(supportDir);
      return supportFiles.FirstOrDefault(this.IsSupportFile);
    }

    private bool IsSupportFile(string path)
      => AutoloadFilenameRegex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(path));
  }
}
```

(see here: https://gist.github.com/felixalmesberger/4ff8ed27f66f872face4368a13123fff)

You can use it like this:

```
var installer = new AutoCadPluginInstaller();
installer.Install(new [] {"Path to dll"});
```

Have fun.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but some of our users may not install the AutoCAD in Program Files directory, that's why I'm trying to get the app list from registry.